# setting up Validations for properties in a process category, Facing error while the code attached below

Tags: pega

I want to put validation for 2 properties like first name and last name should not be same and the age should be b/w 18 to 65, i have created a validate rule in process category,Also added that rule in flowaction validate tab But it is not working. Can u pls help to setup the validations [image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have typed it incorrectly. Each condition should be in different line not using "&&".
In edit you can add condition with "plus" icon to add there you are choosing if this should be and/or.
After correct you should have something like that:

[image]